# Is request.location in geocoder rails gem too slow for heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-geocoder

Over the past week, I've noticed that on pages where I use the Geocoder gem to request.location, my heroku app often displays

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.  
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

The logs show

```
Geocoding API not responding fast enough (use Geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...)
```

I've never noticed this problem before, but perhaps it was always there, it's just that I didn't access the pages with the problem very often until recently. The occurrence of timing out vs. accessing the page seems random.

So I added

```
Geocoder.configure(
  :timeout => 40
)
```

to my config/initializers/geocoder.rb. I think that resulted in accessing the page more often, but it often takes awhile to load.

I'm implementing a default zip code on those pages so that I don't get application errors, but that's not ideal in the long term.

I tried

```
if params[:search].present?
   @events = Event.near(params[:search], params[:dist], order: 'distance') 
elsif user_signed_in? && current_user.address
  @events = Event.near([current_user.latitude, current_user.longitude], 25, order: 'distance') 
elsif request.location 
  @events = Event.near([request.location.latitude, request.location.longitude], 25, order: 'distance') 
else
  @events = Event.near(20016, 100, order: 'distance')
```

expecting to get a default zipcode of 20016 when request.location times out, but I still get the application error.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a timeout for the Geocoder gem you will need to set it to less than 30 seconds, which is how long you have for each request to Heroku. When the timeout is set to 40 seconds, the Geocoder request to the IP geolocation service will timeout after 40 second -- but at the point Heroku has already timed out the request and you see the H12 application error. Set the timeout to something less than 30 seconds and you should at least see the default zip code.

The Geocoder `request.location` method will attempt to geocode the request IP address using the default IP geocoding service, FreeGeoIP. It seems that they have been having some issues recently (Nov, 2015). You might try one of the other IP services (like Telize) to see if that helps the issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Lukas! At some point I had the timeout set to 30, but still had problems. I set the timeout to 20 and replaced the location with "Washington, DC". I think 20016 may not have been a valid value for location. At least now it's vacillating between using request.location and "Washington, DC."

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more clear. If the geocoder timeout is set to 30 you will still see H12 timeouts because the total time of the request will end up being over 30 seconds.